# Error while querying MongoDB database by Parameter with a Nodejs ExpressJS backend --

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

I am trying to query my mongoDB database playerDB and have written a nodeJS and expressJS based backend to query the database. Let me post the relevant piece of codes.

This is the part where I am trying to form the query in server.js -->

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const PORT = 4000;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const playerRoutes = express.Router();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
);

let Player = require('./player.model');
var query = Player.find({ player_: "Hall of Fame" });


playerRoutes.route('/hallOfFame').get(function (req, res) {
    query.exec(function (err, players) {
        if (err) {
            return handleError(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(players);
        }
    });
});
```

This is my player.model.js --

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;


let Player = new Schema({
    player_name: {
        type: String
    },
    player_description: {
        type: String
    },
    player_position: {
        type: String
    },
    player_age: {
        type: String
    },
    player_club: {
        type: String
    },
    player_: {
        type: String
    },
    player_isactive: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    player_completed: {
        type: Boolean
    }
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('player', Player);
```

Basically my player_ attribute is supposed to have the value 'Hall of Fame' and that is what I am trying to query. SO what is the problem here? Where did it go wrong? I experimented around with single and double quotes around the **Hall of Fame** to make sure the issue is not there. When I test my back end with Postman and make a GET request to ***localhost:4000/playerDB/hallOfFame*** I am simply getting blank. Not even null. ***But the noteworthy point is that the Status is showing: 200 OK***

??

I am at a loss completely. What exactly is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You have the schema there, but no model for the schema. Try making a model for the Hall Of Fame player. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html

Comment: hi @Tiago, that player.model.js is not a model that can be used? I have to make another new separate? how should that one be? can you hint a sample? some code for the hall of fame model? I'm quite confused

Comment: You just made a schema for player, so it only has what the player info would be. You need to create an actual player now which would be the model, the link I sent should be pretty straight-forward.

Comment: hi, yes many player records are already added/created to the MongoDB database, I did that part already. now I am trying to query them and that is where it is failing....    @Tiago

Comment: 'Hall of Fame' or ' ' is the value I am saving under player_ if you observe that player schema. Hope you understand what I am trying to explain,